# Node.js Promise concept during if else condition in then block

Tags: mysql, node.js, redis, promise

I have a scenario where the webservice needs to check for existense of key in redis if present give it as a response else get it from mysql, store in redis and then give it as response.

So i am using promises concept where first time when i call **return new Set_Data();** it doesn't go to next **then** block it just stays idle. But next time since data already exists the **return new Set_Data();**
is not executed which is correct.

But why is that i am getting problem for first time when i call **return new Set_Data();** which is not going for next then block.

Below is my code

**constants.js file**

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = 
{
    getRedisConnection: function () 
    {
        return require("redis").createClient(6379, 'path', { auth_pass: 'key' });       
    },
    getMySqlConnection: function () 
    {
       var conObj = { host: "localhost", user: "root", password: "", database: "deccan" };

       var connection = require("mysql").createConnection(conObj);

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
        {
            connection.connect(function (error) 
            { 
                if (error)
                    reject(error);
                else
                    resolve(connection);
            });
        });       
    }
};
```

**webservicefile.js**

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var constants = require("../constants");


function getSettings(request, response) 
{
   var client = constants.getRedisConnection();       

    get_Data();

    function get_Data() 
    {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) 
        {
            client.get("url", function (error, reply) 
            {
                if (error) 
                    reject(error);
                else 
                {
                    if (reply == null)
                        resolve();              // Key not present so create
                    else
                        resolve(reply);
                }
            });
        }).
        catch(function (e) 
        {
            console.log("Error at : " + new Date().toString() + ", => " + e);
        }).
        then(function (urlResult) 
        {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) 
            {
                if (urlResult == undefined || urlResult == null) 
                {
                    return new Set_Data();
                }
                else 
                {
                    client.quit();
                    return resolve(urlResult);
                }
            });
        }).
        then(function (urlResult) 
        {
            if (urlResult) 
                response.status(200).send({ url : urlResult });
            else 
                response.status(500).send();
        })
    }


    function Set_Data()
    {
        constants.getMySqlConnection().then(function (connection)
        {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) 
            {
                connection.query("select url from table where id = 1", function (error, results) 
                {
                    connection.end();

                    if (error)
                        reject(error);
                    else
                        resolve(results);
                });
            });
        }).
        then(function (url) 
        {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) 
            {
                client.set('url', url, function (err, reply) 
                {
                    if (err)
                        reject(err);
                    else
                        resolve(url);
                });
            });

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: when `(urlResult == undefined || urlResult == null)`, that promise is never resolved or rejected

Comment: Jaronmanda, if you see Set_Data(); function in the last then block its actually returning reject or resolve so it should be correct right ?

Comment: OK, let me be clearer .. the Promise created and returned on line 37 of *webservicefile.js* is **never** resolved or rejected in the case where `(urlResult == undefined || urlResult == null)` ... I could go back and unravel the spaghetti code to tell you the exact circumstances this happens, but I think you already know when this happens as you stated that *it doesn't go to next then block it just stays idle* - a pending Promise remains pending until it is resolved or rejected. Returning something in the promise create function does nothing, you must call the `resolve` or `reject` callback

Comment: so what changes should I make when the if condition is true by waiting for the response from Set_Data() function so depending upon the response I can call resolve or reject. 
I tried but I am still not able to achieve so can you please let me know the changes what needs to be done

Comment: To be honest, I can't follow the logic of your code **at all** - clearly knowing where the problem is hasn't helped you figure it out, so I have no chance

Comment: Jaromanda, atleast can you give your way of code for my scenario so that I can follow it. I know its difficult but its too important for me to rectify.
**Problem is :** When a response as arrived check for key in Redis, if exists give it as response else get the value from MySQL, store in Redis and then give it as a response. 

I tried keeping MySQL and Redis connections code in separate file so that I can re-use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of changes should do the trick, first `Set_Data()` doesn't return a promise like you think it does, add a `return`:

```
function Set_Data() {
    return constants.getMySqlConnection().then(function (connection).then()
    // ...      
}
```

Inside this callback, you don't have a `resolve()` in the if so the promise is never resolved, returning something doesn't resolve:

```
// your code
then(function (urlResult) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (urlResult == undefined || urlResult == null) {
            return new Set_Data();
        } else {
            client.quit();
            return resolve(urlResult);
        }
    });
}).
```

Return `Set_Data()` which is now a promise or the url:

```
then(function (urlResult) {
    if (urlResult == undefined || urlResult == null) {
        return new Set_Data();
    } else {
        client.quit();
        return urlResult;
    }
}).
```

On a side note, don't format your js code like C#, `{` shouldn't be on a new line.

Comment: @Sharath So, why is my answer no the one accepted? :x

Answer (score 1):

You can return new Set_Data() directly if no urlResult, or return urlResult otherwise - inside `then` any (non Promise) value returned is a resolved Promise - so the `.then` chain will continue as required

```
function get_Data() {
    // ...
    .then(function (urlResult) {
        // you don't need a "new Promise" here
        if (urlResult == undefined || urlResult == null) {
            return new Set_Data();
        } else {
            client.quit();
            return urlResult;
        }
    })
    // ...
}
```

One thing I noticed in your code is a `.catch` in the middle of your `.then` chain which will effectively turn an error into a fulfilled promise - not sure if that's the behaviour you are looking for. Something else to look out for

Comment: Jaromanda, actually this was the code I mean without promise I tried it earlier, but it always skips and goes to next then block. So that's the reason I put inside the promise. Now with your code above I put return statement in set_Data() so it solved.